# Java7 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message

Tags: java, ssl, java-7, webmethod, java-6

Updated my application from Java6 to Java7 and I am getting the below exception for SSL,

```
pool-2-thread-1, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, unexpected_message
pool-2-thread-1, called closeSocket()
pool-2-thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
pool-2-thread-1, called close()
```

But I am getting this error continuously. I am able to see some success also. What is causing this?

Comment: What do the server logs show? Can you get the same debug trace from the server (i.e. is it a Java server?)?

Comment: @EJP , its a webmethod server . Server logs i really dont have access.

Comment: You're going to have to get access. There's a problem to be solved.

Comment: Hey @neo, i'm currently facing the same issue, i tried every possible solution, but it didn't fly unfortunately, so i was wondering whether you have solved it, thanks in advance.